# How to achieve a render prop like functionality with React Hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to React Hooks and I am writing a Redirector-like component using Hooks. Basically there is a root app that displays whatever should be returned by the StateManager function, in the currentStateDetails field. Step1 and Step2 components have buttons that should transition to the next steps and so on. Where am I going wrong with my understanding? The root app displays the initial component correctly but never updates on clicks from the step components.

```
const StateManager = () => {
const [currentStateDetails, setCurrentStateDetails] = useState({
    componentToRender: <Step1 />,
    currentUserState: 'default'
  });
const [bool, setBool] = useState(false);
const updateView = (dir) => {
    setBool(true);
  };
useEffect(() => {
    if (bool) {
      setCurrentStateDetails({
        componentToRender: <Step2 />,
        currentUserState: 'step-2'
      });
    }
   }, [bool]);
  return [{ currentStateDetails }, updateView];
}
```

Comment: What is `bool`?

Comment: i was trying to use a bool variable to track when the button from one of the step components would be clicked.

Comment: Can you post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Here's example code: https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-firefly-otvhz?file=/src/App.js Something like this?

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).